# Create a new complexType in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I created a `complexType` as following :

```
<xsd:complexType name="type1" mixed="true">
    <xsd:attribute name="quantité" type="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and I want to create a type based on the type above, in order to give a default value to the attribute quantite.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you don't find a better solution, you can use the `default` attribute for `xsd:attribute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xs:complexType name="type2"
                mixed="true">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:restriction base="type1">        
      <xs:attribute name="quantité" 
                    type="xsd:integer"
                    default="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
```